# How to index new files in an event

Tags: angular, file, typescript

I have an event and i want to index a file onto the event like so:

```
event.target.files[0]=newFile;
```

Where newFile is of type File.

I get an error "Failed to set an indexed property on 'FileList': Index property setter is not supported."

Is there another work around?

Comment: No. You can't set a value to readonly attribute. What you really want to do? Why are you trying to store a "file" in the array of files from an event? What is your goal?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I am using https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper for an image cropper. I need to pass an event to it however i need to first edit the image by cropping/rotating the image via EXIF data. I have the cropped image as a file and a base 64 string but i can't pass it to the event that is required,

Comment: Look at the "inputs". `imageBase64 - string - If you don't want to use a file input, you can set a base64 image directly and it will be loaded into the cropper` you don't need to pass an event from an input. You can pass a base64 (string) to the cropper. I use this component too in some apps, it works this way perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<image-cropper [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent" [maintainAspectRatio]="false" [aspectRatio]=""
        [resizeToWidth]="1000" [cropperMinWidth]="" [onlyScaleDown]="true" [roundCropper]="false" format="png"
        outputType="base64" (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)" (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
        (cropperReady)="cropperReady()" (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
        [style.display]="showCropper ? null : 'none'" [alignImage]="'left'"></image-cropper>
```

Adding [resizeToWidth]="1000" will resize the image to desired width.